# POS dynamic rows

Tags: php, javascript

Where do i hold the values of the sale for each row dynamically created?
example table:

```
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>Item #</td><td>Brand</td><td>Model</td><td>Item Decription</td><td>Qty</td><td>Price</td> 
    </tr>
    <tr><td colspan="5"></td><td>Submit</td></tr>
    </table>
```

I need to write the values to a mysql db using php. Right now i'm saving the values in temporary table but its too much overhead it seems. I think I should hold the values in JS variables then insert the record via a loop.

I can honestly say I'm probalbly making this harder than it needs to be.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What is this temporary table, and why does it have a read-only overhead?

Comment: I actually write to the temporary table, my idea to hold the values for each row. The user can then start to buy another item and when the item is clicked, that's when this row is written to the temp table. Then I have it update this table for the qty. When a value is clicked within the qty input, it then updates the temp table for that row.

Comment: I'll ask for clarification again - what is this table? Is it a MySQL table, an HTML table, or a 2-D JavaScript/PHP array?